# If one of the sub-matrices is singular, the whole matrix will be singular?

Tags: matrices

A larger matrix is formed by four sub-matrices A,B,C,D. If one of the sub-matrices is singular, the whole matrix will be singular?

Comment: Hint: Consider the $2\times 2$ case where one of the entries is $0$.

Comment: Hint: Consider various submatrices of the identity matrix.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the "block matrix" 
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 \\
0 & 1 \\
\end{pmatrix}$$
where the "blocks" are $1\times 1$ submatrices. Then the bottom left block is singular, whereas the block matrix has determinant $1$ (being the identity).

Comment: what happen if the bottom right block is singular? then

Comment: Then you can consider the alternate example
$(1, 1; 1, 0)$...

Comment: if a singular sub-matrix is present in the main diagonal of the matrix, the matrix will becomes singular?

Comment: No, see my example above :)

Comment: My question is: is a matrix A formed by 3X3 sub-matrices singular if one of the sub-matrices located in the main diagonal of the matrix is singular? That means there are some kind of compatible condition needs to be satisfied for the system Ax=B to have unique solution.

Comment: No, you can construct a counterexample for this case pretty easily also. Set $A=0_{3\times 3}$ and $B=I_{3\times 3}$, and consider $(A, B; B, A)$ which is non-singular, even though *both* diagonal blocks are the zero matrix.